# How to remove transients in time-series data in Python (or Pandas)?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, time-series

I have a time-series set of data recording the flow and temperature of a heat pump. The first few minutes when the system kicks on, the flows and temperatures aren't fully developed and I'd like to filter them out.

```
Time (min)  Flow    Supply T    Return T
….          
45  0   0   0
46  0   0   0
47  1.338375    92.711328   78.72152
48  2.267975    82.578552   74.239624
49  0.778125    96.073136   74.288664
50  0.778125    101.3998    74.686288
51  0.7885  102.1189    74.490528
….
```

For instance, the first 3 minutes of operation (from 47-49 minutes), don't do any calculations with the data.
I can do that with a loop, but the data set is very large (>200 mb text file) and takes a really long time to loop through. I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to pull it out, perhaps using Pandas?

Any help or advice is appreciated! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So what are you asking? how to drop all rows after 49th minute or you want to drop just rows 47:49?

Comment: I want to drop rows 47:49. I have a loop that looks for at least 3 consecutive flows>0 before calculating energy, however this data file is huge and I haven't been able to work with the whole file yet without crashing. I've used Pandas in the past for resampling and like how quickly it deals with large data, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do filtering like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following, I think it should work, basically it filters out the rows where row at `n-3` does not equal 0 and is not `NaN` this assumes that when there is no flow you have a value of 0:

```
In [12]:

df[(df.Flow.shift(3)!=0) & (df.Flow.shift(3).notnull())]
Out[12]:
   Time_(min)      Flow  Supply_T   Return_T
5          50  0.778125  101.3998  74.686288
6          51  0.788500  102.1189  74.490528
```